# Transactions fail with "execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"

Tags: node.js, solidity, remix, ethers.js, uniswap

**My bot makes swaps using UniswapV2Router from basetoken->token then token-> basetoken, from a random list using the following method.**

```
const tx = await swapper.connect(owner).duelDexTrade(router1,router2,baseToken,token,amount)
await tx.wait()
console.log(tx)
```

**I approve amounts for the router(spookyswap or spiritswap) the amouts before each swap.**

```
function swap (address _router, address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint _amount) private onlyOwner {
    IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(_router,_amount);  // Approve router to spend.
    address[] memory path;  
    path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = _tokenIn;
    path[1] = _tokenOut;
    uint deadline = block.timestamp+300;
    IUniswapV2Router02(_router).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amount,1,path, address(this), deadline);
}
```

**When I run the console, the first transaction (irrespective of the pair) always goes through, and the following transactions all fail with the error:**

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
reason="execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"
```

**When I stop the console and start again, the first transaction goes through followed by the above error. Every time same result. I am using hh and ethersjs. Any help is welcome.**

Comment: are you sure you are not missing any approve call?

Comment: I approve amounts to swap in the swap function for each router (spooky or spirit). The first transaction always goes through. The error pops up from the 2nd onwards.